# Get input from front-end of the website and generate file corresponding in python

Tags: python, flask

i am creating an website in which the users are going to input some form data and from the form data that the user given i will generate a excel file based on it using python, my python script is already done, but i dont know how i can connect it to the front-end / javascript so the  i can pass the data to my python file script download the excel file to the user, i was looking at some django / flask tutorials but haven't found nothing that solves my problem, thanks for any reply in advance

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you could show some dummy code you have tried yourself.

So as I understand, you have a script.py ready that will generate the excel file and tested it yourself in command line. But you're not sure how to implement in the Django and get desired results.

Define a function in your `views.py` file along the lines of:

```
def excel_creator(param1,param2):...
```

- Transform your `script.py` code into the function *excel_creator*.
- Then get the user input (e.g. `request.POST.get()...`)
- Call the function and those input values as parameters
- Then work on making the output file downloadable for user (refer Django official documentations).

Answer (score -1):

First you need to have a Django or Flask project. Let's say, Django.

1. Then you an endpoint for API.
2. POST the data from frontend to back-end using that API end point.
3. Once the data received on django side, run your script and download the
   excel file. You can send that excel file to front-end as well for
   download.